# How to make a form page element load its innerText before evaluating the page response using Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a Puppeteer project that fills out a form input field, presses a button, then extracts the result that appears in a second form field (`'#texta'`).

I expect the `result` to be the string that appears in the second field (`'#texta'`) after it populates. I actually get an empty string. This suggests to me that `page.evaluate()` is being called before the form server returns the response triggered by pressing the run button.

How to I get Puppeteer to wait until the target form field populates? What am I doing wrong?

puppeteer.js

```js
const waitUntilLoad = {
  waitUntil: 'load',
};

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto( url, waitUntilLoad, );
await page.click( listCheckboxSelector, );
await page.type( formInputSelector, targetList, );
await page.click( runButtonSelector, );

// this is the problematic section
// how to I make it wait for '#texta' element to populate its innerText?
const result = await page.evaluate( () =>
  document.querySelector('#txta') && document.querySelector('#txta').innerText.trim()
, waitUntilLoad, );

console.log( 'result\n', result, ); // expected: content, actual: null
console.log( 'result type: ', typeof result, ); // expected: string, actual: string
console.log( 'result length: ', result.length, ); // expected: number > 0, actual: 0

await browser.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait for any complex scenario with `page.waitFor` passing it a function (or just use [page.waitForFunction](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforfunctionpagefunction-options-args)):

```
await page.waitFor( () =>  document.querySelector('#txta').innerText.trim() !== "")
```

As soon as the passed function returns a truthy value, the wait is over and the script continues.